# Find files containing multiple strings

Tags: string, unix, search, grep, find

I use a command to recursively find files containing a certain `string1`:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -H string1 {} \;
```

I need to find files containing multiple strings, so the command should return those containing all strings. Something like this:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -H string1 AND string2 {} \;
```

I couldn't find a way. The strings can be anywhere in the files. Even a solution for only two strings would be nice.

Comment: I could translate your question to an "egrep" question: the command `egrep -l "string1|string2"` gives all the files which contain `string1` OR `string2`, in case a parameter exist in order to make `egrep -l "string1 <parameter> string2"`give the files which contain `string1` AND `string2`, your question would be solved. (I don't know if such a parameter exists, though)

Comment: There could theoretically be a union operator `&` just like `|` corresponds to intersection, but no common regex tools implement this. The easy fix is `awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/'` so there is already a simple way to do exactly this, albeit not with `grep`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can also try this;

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l 'string1' {} \; | xargs grep -l 'string2'
```

this shows file names that contain  string1 and string2

Comment: This is a very nice solution. I suggest surrounding `{}` with single quotes and using the `-d` argument to `xargs` to avoid errors due to filenames with spaces, like this:

`find . -type f -exec grep -l 'string1' '{}' \; | xargs -d '\n' grep -l 'string2'`

Comment: I would also suggest using a `+` instead of `\;` to end the `-exec` option of the find command.  This will search as many files as possible with a single grep command, reducing the number of processes that will run, resulting in a much quicker result.

Answer (score 6):

You can chain your actions and use the exit status of the first one to only execute the second one if the first one was successful. (Omitting the operator between primaries defaults to `-and`/`-a`.)

```bash
find . -type f -exec grep -q 'string1' {} \; -exec grep -H 'string2' {} \;
```

The first grep command uses `-q`, "quiet", which returns a successful exit status if the string was found.

To collect all files containing `string1` and then run the search for `string2` with just a single invocation of grep, you could use `-exec ... {} +`:

```bash
find . -type f -exec grep -q 'string1' {} \; -exec grep 'string2' {} +
```

Answer (score 5):

with GNU `grep`

```
grep -rlZ 'string1' | xargs -0 grep -l 'string2'
```

from `man grep`

> -r, --recursive
>
> Read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic
>   links only if they are on the command line. Note that if no file
>   operand is given, grep searches the working directory. This is
>   equivalent to the -d recurse option.
>
> -Z, --null
>   Output a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of the character  that  normally  follows  a  file
>   name.   For  example,  grep  -lZ outputs a zero byte after each file name instead of the usual newline.
>   This option makes the output unambiguous, even  in  the  presence  of  file  names  containing  unusual
>   characters  like  newlines.  This option can be used with commands like find -print0, perl -0, sort -z,
>   and xargs -0 to process arbitrary file names, even those that contain newline characters.

Answer (score 3):

Amazed that this old question lacks the obvious simple Awk solution:

```
find . -type f -exec awk '/string1/ && /string2/ { print; r=1 } END { exit 1-r }' {} \;
```

The trickery with the `r` variable is just to emulate the exit code from `grep` (zero means found, one means not; if you don't care, you can take that out).

For efficiency, maybe switch from `-exec ... {} \;` to `-exec ... {} +` though then you might want to refactor the Awk script a bit (either throw out the exit code, or change it so the exit code indicates something like "no files matched" vs "only some files matched" vs "all files matched"?)

The above code looks for files which contain both strings on the same line. The case of finding them on any lines is an easy change.

```
awk '/string1/ { s1=1 }
  /string2/ { s2=1 }
  s1 && s2 { print FILENAME; exit }
  END { exit(1 - (s1 && s2)) }' file
```

This just prints the name of the file, and assumes that you have a single input file. For processing multiple files, refactor slightly, to reset the values of `s1` and `s2` when visiting a new file:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 { s1 = s2 = 0 }
  /string1/ { s1 = 1 }
  /string2/ { s2 = 1 }
  s1 && s2 { r=1; print FILENAME; nextfile }
  END { exit 1-r }' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Some ancient Awk versions might not support `nextfile`, though it is now in POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer

As you can see from the other answers on this page, there are several command-line tools that can be used to perform conjunctive searching across files. A fast and flexible solution that has not yet been posted is to use [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher):

```
ag -l string1 | xargs ag -l string2
```

#### Useful variations

For case-insensitive searching, use the `-i` option of `ag`:

```
ag -il string1 | xargs ag -il string2
```

For additional search terms, extend the pipeline:

```
ag -l string1 | xargs ag -l string2 | xargs ag -l string3 | xargs ag -l string4
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
grep -rlZ string1 | xargs -0 grep -l string2
```

If your patterns are fixed strings, we can speed up the command by adding `-F` to grep:

```sh
grep -rlZF string1 | xargs -0 grep -lF string2
```