# Find two strings in a list of files and get filename

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have the following files:

```
100005.txt  107984.txt  116095.txt  124152.txt  133339.txt  139345.txt  18147.txt  25750.txt  32647.txt  40390.txt  48979.txt  56502.txt  64234.txt  72964.txt  80311.txt  888.txt    95969.txt
100176.txt  108084.txt  116194.txt  124321.txt  133435.txt  139438.txt  18331.txt  25940.txt  32726.txt  40489.txt  49080.txt  56506.txt  64323.txt  73063.txt  80481.txt  88958.txt  9601.txt
100347.txt  108255.txt  116378.txt  124494.txt  133531.txt  139976.txt  18420.txt  26034.txt  32814.txt  40589.txt  49082.txt  56596.txt  64414.txt  73163.txt  80580.txt  89128.txt  96058.txt
100447.txt  108343.txt  116467.txt  124594.txt  133627.txt  140519.txt  18509.txt  26128.txt  32903.txt  40854.txt  49254.txt  56768.txt  64418.txt  73498.txt  80616.txt  89228.txt  96148.txt
100617.txt  108432.txt  11647.txt   124766.txt  133728.txt  14053.txt   1866.txt   26227.txt  32993.txt  41026.txt  49308.txt  56857.txt  6449.txt   73670.txt  80704.txt  89400.txt  96239.txt
10071.txt   108521.txt  116556.txt  124854.txt  133830.txt  141062.txt  18770.txt  26327.txt  33093.txt  41197.txt  49387.txt  57029.txt  64508.txt  7377.txt   80791.txt  89500.txt  96335.txt
100788.txt  10897.txt   116746.txt  124943.txt  133866.txt  141630.txt  18960.txt  2646.txt   33194.txt  41296.txt  4971.txt   57128.txt  64680.txt  73841.txt  80880.txt  89504.txt  96436.txt
```

Some of the files look like:

```
spec: 
  annotations: 
    name: "ubuntu4"
    labels: 
      key: "cont_name"
      value: "ubuntuContainer4"

    labels: 
      key: "cont_service"
      value: "UbuntuService4"


  task: 
    container: 
      image: "ubuntu:latest"
      args: "tail"
      args: "-f"
      args: "/dev/null"
      mounts: 
        source: "/home/testVolume"
        target: "/opt"
      replicated: 
        replicas: 1
```

I want to get every filename that contains *ubuntu* **AND** *replicas*.

I have tried `awk '/ubuntu/ && /replicas/{print FILENAME}' *.txt` but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This kind of answers it: [Find files containing mutiple strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39851255/1983854)

Comment: Is the order of appearance always the same, first Ubuntu, then replica?

Comment: Thank you for guiding me to that post!

Comment: @userunknown yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grep can return a list of the files that match a string.  You can nest that grep call so that you first get a list of files that match **ubuntu**,  then use that list of files to get a list of files that match **replicas**.

```
grep -l replicas $( grep -l ubuntu *.txt )
```

This does assume that at least one file will match ubuntu.  To get around that limitation, you can add a test for the existence of one file first, and then do the combined search:

```
grep -q ubuntu *.txt && grep -l replicas $( grep -l ubuntu *.txt )
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Thank you, @Aaron.  I added more of an explanation above.

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for improving your answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Check if both strings appear in a given file by using a counter for each and then checking if they were incremented. You can do this with [`BEGINFILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html), available on GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGINFILE {ub=0; re=0}
     /ubuntu/ {ub++}
     /replicas/ {re++}
     (ub>0 && re>0) {print FILENAME; nextfile}' *.txt
```

This sets two counters to 0 when it starts to read a file: one for one string and another one for the other. When one of the patterns is found, it increments its corresponding counter. Then it keeps checking if the two counters have been incremented. If so, it prints its filename using the `FILENAME` variable that contains that string. Also, it skips the rest of the file using [`nextfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html), since there is no need to continue checking for the patterns.

Comment: Is initializing the values to 0 a best-practice, or maybe a portability consideration? I'm not a big `awk` user but I've always relied on the default initialization to 0 or empty string and I'd like to know if I should avoid this in the future :)

Comment: can't get it work, I ended up using `grep -l replicas $( grep -l ubuntu *.txt )`

Comment: @Aaron on the first iteration it is not necessary, but note that `BEGINFILE` happens every time a new file is processed. So it is necessary to reset the counter that were used for the previous file.

Comment: @fedorqui alright, not quite the same thing then ; I guess I never had to variables while handling multiple files with `awk`. Thanks for the info !

Comment: @Aaron it is handy to use `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE`. However, this is more a way to show this functionality than a good, pertinent solution. The way to go is what Charlie suggested, by using `grep`.

Comment: Well I guess it depends, Charlie's solution is much more simple and readable and I'd suggest it in general, but if performances are a concern yours is better since it will only read the files once, while Charlie's will have to read some of them twice.

Comment: @Aaron uhms, you are right. Thanks to your interest, I have done some improving and now I use `nextfile` instead, so there is no need to continue reading the file after we know that the two patterns occur in the file.

Comment: @hichamx this may have to do with the fact that this is GNU awk specific.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/ubuntu/ && /replicas/{print FILENAME}' *.txt
```

looks for both regexps on the same line. To find them both in the same file but possibly on separate lines with GNU awk for ENDFILE is:

```
awk '/ubuntu/{u=1} /replicas/{r=1} ENDFILE{if (u && r) print FILENAME; u=r=0}' *.txt
```

or more efficiently adding gawks nextfile construct and preferentially switching to BEGINFILE (as @fedorqui already showed) instead of ENDFILE since all that remains between file reads is to set the 2 variables:

```
awk 'BEGINFILE{u=r=0} /ubuntu/{u=1} /replicas/{r=1} u && r{print FILENAME; nextfile}' *.txt
```

With other awks it'd be:

```
awk '
    FNR==1{prt()} /ubuntu/{u=1} /replicas/{r=1} END{prt()}
    function prt() {if (u && r) print fname; fname=FILENAME; u=r=0}
' *.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for showing how to do it with a non-GNU awk!

Answer (score 1):

If no subdirs have to been visited:

```
for f in *.txt 
do  
   grep -q -m1 'ubuntu' $f && grep -q -m1 'replicas' $f && echo "found: $f" 
done
```

or as oneliner:

```
for f in *.txt ; do  grep -q -m1 'ubuntu' $f && grep -q -m1 replicas $f && echo found:$f ; done
```

The -q makes grep quiet, so the matches aren't display, the -m1 only searches for 1 match, so grep can report a match fast.

The && is short circuiting, so if the first grep doesn't find anything, the second isn't tried.

For working on the files further down the pipeline, you will of course eliminate the chatty "found: ".

Comment: Thank you! works perfectly.