# Function to grep files containing arbitrary number of strings (boolean and)

Tags: bash, grep

I'm hoping to write a bash script to grep files matching several strings.

I've found the 'hard-wired' solution here: (Source: [Find files containing multiple strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39850672/find-files-containing-multiple-strings)):

`find . -type f -exec grep -l 'string1' {} \; | xargs grep -l 'string2' | xargs grep -l 'string3' | xargs grep -l 'string4'`

Would return all files containing `string1` && `string2` && `string3` && `string4`.

How can I convert this into a bash shell function `fn` that takes in an arbitrary number of arguments? I'd like `fn string1 string2 string3 string4 ...` to give me identical results. Persumably this would involve looping through arguments and piping results to successive commands `xargs grep -l ${!i}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `grep` supports `-P` (PCRE) option, how about:

```
# grep files containing arbitrary number of strings
fn() {
    local dir=$1                        # directory to search
    shift
    local -a patterns=("$@")            # list of target strings
    local i                             # local variable
    local pat="(?s)"                    # single mode makes dot match a newline
    for i in "${patterns[@]}"; do
        pat+="$(printf "(?=.*\\\b%s\\\b)" "$i")"
    done
    find . -type f -exec grep -zlP "$pat" {} \;
}

# example of usage
fn . string1 string2 string3
```

If the passed word list is `word1 word2`, it generates a regex pattern
`"(?s)(?=.*\bword1\b)(?=.*\bword2\b)` which matches a file containing
both `word1` and `word2` in any order.

- `(?s)` specifies a "single mode" making a dot match any characters including
  a newline.
- `-z` option to `grep` sets the input record separator to a null character.
  Then the whole file is treated as a single line.

If `grep -P` is not available, here is an alternative using a loop:

```
fn() {
    local dir=$1                        # directory to search
    shift
    local -a patterns=("$@")            # list of target strings
    local i f flag                      # local variables

    while IFS= read -rd "" f; do        # loop over the files fed by "find"
        fail=0                          # flag to indicate match fails
        for i in "${patterns[@]}"; do   # loop over the target strings
            grep -q "$i" "$f" || { fail=1; break; }
                                        # if not matched, set the flag and exit the loop
        done
        (( fail == 0 )) && echo "$f"    # if all matched, print the filename
    done < <(find . -type f -print0)
}
```

Comment: OP is not looking for lines containing all the patterns. They want files which match all the patterns, not necessarily on the same line. So your first solution doesn't work.

Comment: @rici oh! that's right. I've fixed the code to match words on different lines. Thank you so much for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks! Note: \\\b in the first version means that it only greps whole word matches only.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. That's correct. If you want to make e.g `str` match not only `str` but also `string`, just drop `\\\b`s. BR.